# Copy data from one table to another with constraints in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables in Oracle, defined as the following:

**Location Data**

```
loc_id
capacity
loc_type
```

**User Data**

```
loc_id
custom001
```

What I'm wanting to do is copy what's in location.capacity into user.custom001 if the following constraints are met:

custom001 <> capacity

loc_type IN ('A','B')

capacity is not NULL or 0

Based on some other queries I've found on Stack Exchange, I've developed this:

```
UPDATE user u 
SET u.custom001 = 
  (SELECT l.capacity
  FROM location l
  WHERE u.loc_id = l.loc_id
  AND l.capacity <> u.custom001
  AND l.loc_type IN ('110','210')
  AND l.capacity IS NOT NULL 
  AND l.capacity <> 0)
WHERE exists (select capacity from location l WHERE l.loc_id = u.loc_id)
```

But it's not respecting the constraints and is updating most every row in the user table, most of them with NULLs.

Where do I need to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.
The following should work:

```
UPDATE user u 
SET u.custom001 = (
  SELECT l.capacity
  FROM location l
  WHERE u.loc_id = l.loc_id
) where exists (
  select null from location l 
  WHERE l.loc_id = u.loc_id
  AND l.capacity <> u.custom001
  AND l.loc_type IN ('110','210')
  AND l.capacity IS NOT NULL 
  AND l.capacity <> 0
)
```

The basic issue with what you have is that you're applying all the restrictions, but then updating everything anyway due to the restrictions not existing in your `WHERE exists` clause

Comment: Worked great.  I thought about trying to move all the constraints to the back end check, but said "nah, that won't work!"  turns out it did.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approch and works well for me . You can use sql Developer to generate the ddl of the table . Then you can create new table with constraints , like primary key , not null constraint and foreign key from the generated ddl . If your table just ahs not null constraint use 
Create table new_table as ( select * from old_table);